# @OneTOOne Mapping not save MySQL. JpaRepository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two model in One to One relation, but when t try to save its provide an ID Error,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_a_table")
class A {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private B b;

    ...
    // Constructor
    // Getter & Setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_b_table")
class B {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private A a;

    ...
    // Constructor
    // Getter & Setter
}
```

When I tried to save like below

```
A newA = new A()
B newB = New B()

newB.setProperties().....

newA.setB(newB);

aRepository.save(newA);
```

An Exception thrown Column 'A_ID' cannot be null

How I can avoid the conflict

Comment: persist `newB` first or make sure you `cascade` is on point

Comment: please provide the stacktrace of the exception

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is bidirectional, thus you also have to maintain it that way:

```
A newA = new A()
B newB = New B()

newB.setProperties().....

newA.setB(newB);
// add this:
newB.setA(newA);

aRepository.save(newA);
```